# How do I unwrap a mesh after using the Boolean tool?

Tags: uv

I used two rectangle meshes and the boolean modifier to cut out holes for my house, but it left me with some geometry like this:
[image]

How do I unwrap this? Even my best attempt (shown below) still has stretching.
[image]

Here is the file
https://drive.google.com/file/d/16swON_OrqXkMk9nR01ZXSvMkO9rzHpOA/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is too vague, the way you need to unwrap completely depends on how you want to put your textures on the object afterwards. But I see at least 2 ways to do it from your current object, and in both cases the UVs will be orthogonal:

**Unwrap with seams**: to create seams (seams are where the unwrap will cut off separate parts), select the edges you want and press <kbd>U</kbd> > *Mark Seam*:

[image]

Then unwrap with the first option (*Unwrap*), here is what it will give:

[image]

**Unwrap with Smart UV Project**: This time you'll let Blender unwrap automatically, the UVs will be separate according to the angles of the faces (you can set the angle you want in the *Operator* box but the default setting, 66°, is ok):

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much I love you moonboots. Do you have a donation box I can donate to?

Comment: thanks, you're welcome, I don't have any donation box actually  ;)

Comment: you should consider having one (if you want of course) and post a link in your bio, I've seen a lot of people do it.